# persistent cpu throttling

Tags: power-management

I like to disable 'TurboBoost' and set the maximum CPU speed to a lower value. That means that ongoing calculations would take some more time, but on the other hand the computer runs quiter and has a better battery life, and maybe even more calculations per battery charge.

I tried something like `echo 2000000 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` as root for every CPU core. However, this setup is lost if I restart the system, and even on every standby cycle.

Where to put this commands to make the change permanent? How can I enable an unprevileged user to invoke this command and adjust the frequency on his demand?

Comment: Turbo boost may actually save battery life with doing things faster and using less power wasted in display, memory, disk and other areas. and there is this:http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM3NTI

Comment: Thats true, as the CPU only consumes a part of the total consumption, a longer calculation consumes more energy. On the other hand, the CPU consumptions rises overproportionally on the MHz so it may be better to slow down things. However, there is still the benefit of silent work, if passive or very low fan cooling is enough, which it is definitely not when using TurboBoost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found there is a tool set named 'TLP' (http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) that beside a vast collection of other power saving settings is able to set the maximal CPU frequency for AC and battery use on the users preference. It is no clean solution to the question because it does many more things, but most of them are useful too...

After installation, one can modify the configuration at `/etc/default/tlp`. There are two entries for that: `CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC` and `CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT`. The values given there will be used by the TLP scripts to set the CPU frequency limits depending on if a battery is used or not, and it will restore the values after suspend and standby too. Changes to the config can be activated immediately using `sudo tlp start`.

Answer (score 1):

TurboBoos can be disabled only in BIOS settings, if you have no such option there you can't disble TurboBoost short of customizing BIOS ROM. 
To update value in such files from console use 
`echo -n 100 > /proc/filename`. Values are not generally stored anywhere. 
To allow non-root to do it, create a script that modifies values, and use `visudo` to allow access to script.

Comment: TurboBoost can be disabled by lowering the scaling_max_freq below the factory maximum of the CPU. The frequency doesn't raise above the given value and thus TurboBoost is inactive. I know how to set the value, using `echo` like you suggest for example. But the problem is that the setting is reset under certain events, like awakening from standby. So my personal preference value has to be stored sokmewhere and should be applied by the machinery that changes the values on standby wakeup... but what scripts or daemons are responsible for that?